# Flutter Firestore group collection query is not synced with DB

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've implemented a group collection query (against Firestore DB) in my Flutter app.

Used to work fine, but in the last couple of days it gives me unexpected results **(basically the results of the query don't reflects the true state of the DB)**:

1. It doesn't show me 'old' documents (created a couple of days ago)
2. If I delete documents from the DB, the query still return those documents
3. If I change some fields in those documents, I don't see it reflects on my query

Using latest plugins versions:

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

My DB structure:

```
Collection   Docs    Collection   Docs (a field called 'group_id')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
users        userA   events       eventA1 ('group_id' = 'G1')
                                  eventA2 ('group_id' = 'G1')
             userB   events       eventB1 ('group_id' = 'G1')
                                  eventB2 ('group_id' = 'G1')
             userC
             userD   events       eventD1 ('group_id' = 'G2')
             userE   events       eventE1 ('group_id' = 'G2')
                                  eventE2 ('group_id' = 'G2')
                                  eventE3 ('group_id' = 'G2')
                                  eventE4 ('group_id' = 'G2')
```

My query:

```
StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _eventsDataListener = Firestore.instance
      .collectionGroup('events')
      .where('group_id', isEqualTo: 'G1')
      .snapshots()
      .listen(onEventsData);
```

**An observation:**
When I delete the '.where' part, hot-reload, rewrite the '.where' part and hot-reload again - it updates and shows the true state of the DB.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share us the code how you call the `_eventsDataListener`?

Comment: Not sure I understand...
I register the _eventsDataListener listener on initState() function